# JAVA Synchronize cycle with callbacks

Tags: java, callback, wait, cycle

I have this function that downloads all files in the ArrayList and I want to make this "synchronous" , I mean that I want to download only one file at time.

How can I make the FOR cycle to wait until a file is downloaded and than take an other file to download?

```
public void downloadFiles(ArrayList<String> files, final String destinationFolder){
  for(String file:files){
    GoogleDrive.getInstance().readFile(file, GoogleDrive.FolderLocation.ROOT_FOLDER, new GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveReadFileCallback() {
         @Override
         public void successful(String title, byte[] content) {
           try {
             FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(destinationFolder+File.pathSeparator+title), content);
           } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.e(TAG,"ERROR FileManager.downloadFiles: "+e.toString());
           }
        }
        @Override
        public void notFound() { }
        @Override
        public void error(String error) { }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, I typically start writing code that works in a sequential manner; before later adding parallelism. Interesting approach to first solve the much more complicated issue ;-)

Comment: Isn't there anything in the API documentation that tells if you read is might be done synchronously?
Also, you can specific in the callback the read to the next element and in that way serialize every request.

Comment: Still an interesting question; have my vote!

Answer (score 2):

The question sounds pretty simple; but turns out to be *hard*. Why is that? Because the given code is doing things in a **wrong** way. What do I mean with that?

I **assume** that

```
GoogleDrive.getInstance().readFile(file,
  GoogleDrive.FolderLocation.ROOT_FOLDER, 
  new GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveReadFileCallback()
```

triggers an *asynchronous* read from Google Drive; and **upon** competition, that callback instance will be called. But when we have a closer look into that callback code - we find that it is missing essential parts:

- it is **not** doing any kind of error handling (hint: you have **no** idea when something went wrong with this approach)
- the callback has no means to "signal" to the outside world "i am done".

Thus: the solution is to rework that thing completely. You could create a real class implementing the required interface; and that callback implementation could have methods that tell you whether file reading is still ongoing, completed successfully or failed.

In other words: you build a *wrapper* around GoogleDrive `readFile()`; and that wrapper offers synchronous reading (probably `successfull()` gets called when the `readFile()` is done - so your wrapper can simply wait for that callback); or the wrapper could return some sort of [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: I agree with you that the solution is incomplete. But I don't think that this answers the questions posed by OP.

Comment: I think that hits the spot.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for the reply but the question is very simple, I have a list with the names of files to download and what I want now is simply to download files one after other not all at once as it is now. As for the wrapper it returns successful,notFound and error nothing more

Comment: your answer doesn't match with my question but since you spend time in writing 190 words I will upvote your answer

Comment: Appreciated! And I will see how to make it more obvious how those two answers are aligned :-)

Answer (score 1):

24 hours later the answear was too easy, just implemented a listener that start a new download every time an old one is terminated(with success or not) and remove it from the list. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it but it works

```
interface FileManagerDownloadEvent{
    void downloadSuccessful(String fileName);
    void downloadNotFound(String fileName);
    void downloadError(String fileName,String error);
}

public class FileManager implements FileManagerDownloadEvent{

        private FileManagerDownloadEvent downloadEvent;
        private ArrayList<String> filesToDownload;
        private String destinationFolder;

        public FileManager(){
            this.downloadEvent=this;
        }

        private void download(){
            if(filesToDownload.size()!=0) {
                final String file=filesToDownload.get(0);
                filesToDownload.remove(0);

                GoogleDrive.getInstance().readFile(file, GoogleDrive.FolderLocation.ROOT_FOLDER, new GoogleDrive.GoogleDriveReadFileCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void successful(String title, byte[] content) {
                        try {
                            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(destinationFolder+File.separator+title), content);
                            downloadEvent.downloadSuccessful(destinationFolder+File.separator+title);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"ERROR FileManager.downloadFiles: "+e.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void notFound() {
                        downloadEvent.downloadNotFound(file);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void error(String error) {
                        downloadEvent.downloadError(file,error);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void downloadSuccessful(String filePath) {
            Log.d(TAG,"downloadSuccessful: "+filePath);
            download();
        }

        @Override
        public void downloadNotFound(String fileName) {
            Log.e(TAG,"downloadNotFound: "+fileName);
            download();
        }

        @Override
        public void downloadError(String fileName,String error) {
            Log.e(TAG,"downloadError: "+fileName+" --> "+error);
            download();
        }
    }
```